# What is jMeter doing with my requests - it is getting responses but shouldn't

Tags: jmeter

So I made a copy of my jmx file and obfuscated the domain to include here. Be kind. I am a load testing noob. :)

I have a load testing target. I must be on the VPN to access the target's website. When connected to the VPN, my load test numbers make no sense. This is cool. I am not convinced I have the test created correctly. But what is weirder still is that when I am NOT connected to the VPN the requests receive a response. The results tree has pretty little green checkmarks (well really shield icons). But there is no way it should have been able to communicate with the server. But when I look at response body, it is a very reasonably approriate response body.

My jmx file is too big. I will try to attach it. But does anyone have an explanation for what might be going on? Or what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These "pretty little green checkmarks" doesn't mean that you're hitting the correct server, JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful so my expectation is that you're basically hitting some form of VPN web gateway login page or something like this and JMeter considers these redirects as successful responses.

You can inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and see what exact host you're hitting and what does the response say.

Going forward in order to protect yourself from these "false positive" results you can consider adding [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to your requests to ensure that response contains what it is supposed to be containing or alternatively doesn't contain errors

Comment: I understand what you said (sort of). Looking at the View Results Tree I am seeing what looks like actual HTML page response. As I look at it, I see an HTML page that looks right-ish. I saved my tree results into a file as the jMeter feature allows. I see in that xml file the first request has a testResults node which has an httpSample note with hn attribute pointing to my local server. Is this my culprit? I don't know how to fix/identify that I am "hitting some form of VPN web gateway login page or something like this" so that it is not doing so. Sorry not a network expert. Learning! Thanks.